# Codeigniter view not letting me use subdirectory

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Background**

I am using this custom modification Codeigniter in order to allow me to use static header and footer. But since I started using it whenever I create a folder in my views folder and put my view file in there and try loading the view it doesn't pass the variables through to the view from the controller.

**The Code**

**The modification for static header and footer**

```
<?php 

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
        if($return):
        $content  = $this->view('common/header', $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view('common/footer', $vars, $return);

        return $content;
    else:
        $this->view('common/header', $vars);
        $this->view($template_name, $vars);
        $this->view('common/footer', $vars);
    endif;

    }
}
```

This works fine but only if I put my view file in the view folder itself, the second I put my view in a subfolder in the views folder the variables dont get passed through.

**The Controller using my template function**

```
<?php


class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data['test'] = 'test';
        $this->load->template('sheets/welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

**To sum up**

If I put the view welcome_message.php in the views folder the variables get passed correctly.

If i put the view in a subfolder in the main view folder the variables dont get passed through.

Im not sure why this is happening, been wracking my brain but nothing obvious stands out.

Comment: When you created this folder did you set the permissions correctly?  Apache uses a user called httpd and you probably used your own user.

Answer (score 0):

try use load->views instead;

```
$this->load->views('folderInsideViews/subfolder/view.php', $data);
```